# ORCA INSTALLING ERROR

Tags: make

I am new here and I was trying to intall *orca* but I have some problem.

```
./configure 

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for intltool >= 0.50.0... 0.51.0 found
checking for intltool-update... /usr/bin/intltool-update
checking for intltool-merge... /usr/bin/intltool-merge
checking for intltool-extract... /usr/bin/intltool-extract
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for perl >= 5.8.1... 5.22.1
checking for XML::Parser... ok
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for itstool... itstool
checking for xmllint... xmllint
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for PYGOBJECT... yes
checking for ATSPI2... no
configure: error: Package requirements (atspi-2 >= 2.18) were not met:

No package 'atspi-2' found
```

I have this error but I didn't find *atspi2*.
Help me please.

Comment: Depending on the Ubuntu version, does `apt-get install libatspi2.0-dev` work and make the `configure` not crash?

Comment: Why are you installing orca from source? Does `sudo apt install gnome-orca` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to provide the dependency, which it demands ...

it's the `Assistive Technology Service Provider Interface` [AT-SPI2](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Accessibility/AT-SPI2/).

```
sudo apt-get install libatspi2.0-dev
```

there's also bindings for Qt & Python & a profile manager.